# Select repeated sequence of an number in an array?

Tags: ruby

Given an array of numbers, how can I select the number in the array that's has been repeated the most times?

```
arr = [4,3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0]
```

Comment: Do you mean repeated consecutively, or just repeated?

Comment: @NicholasAlek Do you mean repeated **in a row**? What number wins in this case: `[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]` 2 or 1?

Comment: I see, just repeated. It really doesn't matter in which order numbers come.

Comment: Have you attempted any solution yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here it is for just *repeated*:**

```
arr = [4,3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0]
arr.group_by{|e| e}.max_by{|k,v| v.size}.first
# => 4
```

or

```
arr = [4,3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0]
arr.uniq.max_by{|e| arr.count(e)}
# => 4
```

**Another is for *repeated consecutively* :**

```
arr = [4,3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0]
arr.chunk{|e| e}.max_by{|e| e.last.size}.first
# => 4
```

As per the **@Tessi** [**`Benchmark report`**](https://gist.github.com/tessi/6501753) :

```
require 'benchmark'
iterations = 10_000
arr = Array.new(1000) {(rand()*100).to_i}

def max_babai1(arr)
  arr.group_by{|e| e}.max_by{|k,v| v.size}.first
end

def max_babai2(arr)
  arr.uniq.max_by{|e| arr.count(e)}
end

Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  bm.report('babai1') do
    iterations.times do
      max_babai1 arr
    end
  end

  bm.report('babai2') do
    iterations.times do
      max_babai2 arr
    end
  end
end
```

**Output**

```
ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]

ruby bench.rb         
       user     system      total        real
babai1  1.700000   0.000000   1.700000 (  1.707292)
babai2 29.630000   0.010000  29.640000 ( 29.769966)
```

Comment: That's the one!!! Thanks. Can you walk me through your code?

Comment: @NicholasAlek which one is your one? First one(*repeated*) or last one(*repeated consecutively*) ? :)

Comment: Ahhh, doesn't matter which order, first or last.

Comment: for the `repeated` one you can use `chunk` if you sort first: `arr.sort.chunk{|v|v}.max_by{|val,a| a.size}.first`. Although neither implementation handles ties.

Comment: @firien why sort is needed ? You probably didn't catch the difference between the 2 codes.

Comment: i don't believe the repeated consecutively works. put a "5" in the first slot and check the result. and yes i understood the difference

Comment: @firien give me the array please..:) I will test it.

Comment: arr = [5,4,3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0]
arr.chunk{|e| e}.max_by{|e| e.size}.first

Comment: @firien fixed it now.. :)

Comment: @firien see now - `arr = [5,4,3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
arr.chunk{|e| e}.max_by{|e| e.last.size}.first
# => 5` ..

Comment: yep. so my point was that you could use your exact same code from _repeated consecutively_ to find most _duplicates_ if you threw a `sort` in right before `chunk.`

Comment: @firien see my update. It is more elegant! :)

Comment: I *highly* suggest to use @Babai's first approach. The second one is an order of magnitude slower: https://gist.github.com/tessi/6501753

Comment: @tessi I have added the benchmark report! :)

Comment: Wow. The first line of code wins by miles! What a difference it makes to know which method would work the best. Thanks @Babai!